# synopsys dc_shell get_attribute number of digits

Tags: tcl, precision, synopsys-vcs

In order to perform some optimizing algorithm, I need a good degree of precision in getting attributes from tcl dc_shell (synopsys Version D-2010.03-SP3). 
For example

```
get_attribute CORE65LPLVT/HS65_LL_IVX9 cell_leakage_power
```

returns me 0.000001 while the actual value was 1.381e-6 (obtained through report_power).

I tried

```
set report_default_significant_digits 10
```

but nothing changed.
How can I get more significant digits?

Comment: Ugh, there's a float formatting operation in there somewhere. You'll need a Synopsis expert to help…

Comment: Uhm... Any idea on how to get this expert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The global number of significant digits is set by the command below. The value must be between 0 and 13. `Set` command doesn't change the application variables, but `set_app_var` does.

```
set_app_var report_default_significant_digits 10
```

This variable can be set to its default value later.

```
set_app_var report_default_significant_digits -default
```

Most of the reporting commands also accept the following switch.

```
-significant_digits 10
```

Comment: I accepted your answer to help people who are looking for this. I don't have a copy of dc_shell to try, but I guess it makes sense to be able to distinguish between app-level and script-level variables! Thank you! :)